# Override Panic Handler of Rust std

Tags: rust, panic

I'm currently experimenting with writing a kernel in Rust. I've just found out the by using

```
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "std", "panic_abort"]
```

I can build the standard library from source and then use it. Obviously many of the features won't be working initially.

Currently I'm trying to get `panic!()` to work, and from the implementation it's clear that
`panic` panics because it tries to print the stack trace.

[std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/panicking.rs.html#666):

```
    if must_abort || panics > 2 {
        if panics > 2 {
            // Don't try to print the message in this case
            // - perhaps that is causing the recursive panics.
            rtprintpanic!("thread panicked while processing panic. aborting.\n");
        } else {
            // Unfortunately, this does not print a backtrace, because creating
            // a `Backtrace` will allocate, which we must to avoid here.
            let panicinfo = PanicInfo::internal_constructor(message, location, can_unwind);
            rtprintpanic!("{panicinfo}\npanicked after panic::always_abort(), aborting.\n");
        }
        crate::sys::abort_internal();
    }
```

I've tried adding an infinite loop as a panic hook with the following code after setting up heap allocations:

```
std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| loop {}))
```

but it appears the [print happens before the hook](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/panicking.rs.html#692).

Is there any option to override the default panic handler of the standard library without `#![no_std]`?

**EDIT:**

I'm using `v1.70.0-nightly` with the `#![feature(restricted_std)]` feature.

After @PitaJ's comment I probably should upload all my config files

x86_64-my_os.json

```
{
    "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "64",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

.cargo/config.toml:

```
[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "std", "panic_abort", "compiler_builtins", "alloc"]
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]

[build]
target = "x86_64-my_os.json"

[target.'cfg(target_os = "none")']
runner = "bootimage runner"
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "my_os"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
bootloader = "0.9.8"
linked_list_allocator = "0.10"
```

Comment: Try adding `panic = "abort"` under `[profile.<whatever>]`

Comment: Doesn't work since it's already enabled in the target file.

Comment: Is the problem the backtrace, or the printing? Does printing not work with your OS?

Comment: Well I wouldn't call it an OS yet since its only initializing heap allocations and then try to panic with the right error. It's hard to tell I think it's the printing since the back trace should be disabled with `panic: "abort"` in x86_64-my_os.json. However I can't tell you for sure since I don't have a working debugger for QEMU.

Comment: [tag:std] is C++ tag. Use another tag for Rust.